# two kinds of json payloads to same endpoint in javaxws

Tags: java, json, jax-ws

for example the two payload for the same endpoint, in this case "/payment/purchase" maps json request to correct method. it is possible with jaxws?

```
     payload one
     {
      name:test,
     field1:test1
     }

    payload two
      {
      name:test,
     field2:test2,
      field3:test3
     }

     @POST
 @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })  
 @Path("/payment/purchase")
 public Response someMethod(Request1 orderRequest1) {

     }

     @POST
 @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })  
 @Path("/payment/purchase")
 public Response someMethod2(Request2 orderRequest2) {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I create one big object with all properties and validade using the groups feature of bean validation

http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using

and works fine